Select2 not working on localhost (html-PHP)
I am trying to use select2, but for some reason it does not work. The code below is fairly simple: it pulls data from a Microsoft SQL database, and creates a dropdown list.
All of this is running on a localhost currently.
Tried many different changes but nothing works...
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
        <title>--</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <script src="myScript.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <?php
        $serverName = '--';
        $uid = '--';
        $pwd = '--';
        $databaseName = 'Risk_Management';
        $connectionInfo = array( 'UID'=>$uid,'PWD'=>$pwd,'Database'=>$databaseName);
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
        if($conn){echo '';}else{echo 'Connection failure<br />';die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));}
        // SQL query to select data from mytable
        
        $customer = "SELECT customer FROM Credit_Analysis";
        $resultSet = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $customer) ;
        // Check if query is successful
        
        if( $stmt === false) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
            }
    ?>
    

    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <select class="shortenedSelect" id="#customer">
        <?php
            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultSet, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $customer = $row['customer'];
                echo "<option value = '$customer'>$customer";
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
        
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#customer').select2();
        });
    </script>
    

    </body>
</html>


"Doesn't work" isn't an error message or a useful problem statement. We can't fix "doesn't work" in code, like a mechanic can't fix a car that "doesn't work" without any other information about the problem. How isn't it working? What debugging have you done? What exactly happens when you run this? What did you expect to happen instead? Please provide details of error messages, unexpected behaviour etc. See also What do you mean "It doesn't work"?

Also you'll need to put the script reference to jQuery into your page before the select2 reference, if select2 depends on jQuery. Otherwise you'll get a console error

id="#customer" is also wrong. The selector # doesn't belong in the ID itself. Should be just id="customer". # is what you use in the jquery / JS DOM code / CSS to tell the browser you're looking for something with that ID (as opposed to, say . for a class selector)

yeah sorry for that you're right. Kind of a beginner here with website building here so doing a lot of stuff on the fly unfortunately.
The issue is that the dropdown list doesn't add the search function as it should with the Select2.

fyi, </option> is not required

Is the <body> tag missing (or am I missing it)

Sorry to say, but your code is very messed up :D
Below an example using part of your code, of course without database data. Up to you to adapt
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Ossiano Capital Risk Management</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>


<div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <select class="shortenedSelect" id="customer">
        <option value = '1'>Test 1</option>
        <option value = '2'>Test 2</option>
        <option value = '3'>Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#customer').select2();
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>


haha no worries, not very experienced with this stuff so all help is appreciated.
The dropdown list still remains without the search bar function though :(

I just have the same code and i have the searchbar as well. Any error on your inspector tool console? Try to use my code without any db connection. Then if it works turn on the errors ln your php so you can see what is going wrong here

mmm interesting it works indeed if I don't use the db connection. Thanks for that. Now I know where to dig for the issue!

Btw, also your $stmt var is not declared, so definitely have a look on your db data, connection and so on. Debug every step to find the error

thanks a lot for the advice, its properly working now :)

@Hassaan the first post was edited, you can see the change clicking on "edited 1 hour ago"

@MatteoC glad to hear it. don't understand the downvote on my answer

me neither.....

Here are the issues in your code:

You don't need a # in the ID name. Change <select class="shortenedSelect" id="#customer"> to <select class="shortenedSelect" id="customer">.

You are missing the closing </option> tag at the end of the line echo "<option value='$customer'>$customer";.

Ensure the body tag is correctly opened in the HTML structure.


You need to address the following points as well.

Ensure that jQuery is loaded before the Select2 JavaScript file.

Verify the Select2 and jQuery libraries are being loaded properly.



Thanks for that! I corrected the mistake but i am still getting a dropdown list without the search function unfortunately.

Are you certain about 2.?

I confirm that the regular dropdown worked without the closing option tag. But it works with as well.

@MatteoC, without a closing tag, it might work on your machine/browser, but it can lead to unexpected results on different devices. The standard is to always close HTML tags.
